# SQL Server : fill empty rows with value from previous cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem concerning empty rows; my SQL Server table looks like this:

[image]

The `ItemNo` column for every item is fixed. How can I insert the values for `Label`, `Series` and `Amount` to the `ItemNo`?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE dbo.warehouse 
SET Label Label 
WHERE Label NOT NULL;
```

But it didn't work.

Does anybody have any idea or clue how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate more and you question lacks clarity

Comment: @Computer85 . . . Why are you creating duplicate rows in your table?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    label_2  = FIRST_VALUE(label)  OVER(PARTITION BY itemno ORDER BY id),
    series_2 = FIRST_VALUE(series) OVER(PARTITION BY itemno ORDER BY id),
    amount_2 = FIRST_VALUE(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY itemno ORDER BY id)
  FROM warehouse
)
UPDATE cte
SET label = label_2,
    series = series_2,
    amount = amount_2
WHERE label IS NULL
  AND series IS NULL
  AND Amount IS NULL;
```

Comment: WTH.. thank you very much works like a charm. Thank you Sir you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply an update with join, check other columns if needed I just check for `Label` columns in both tables

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
   ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   ItemNo INT,
   Label VARCHAR(25),
   Series VARCHAR(25),
   Amount INT
);

INSERT INTO T (ItemNo, Label, Series, Amount) VALUES
(111, 'Baer', 'Toys', 9),
(111, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(222, 'Flower', 'Garden', 8),
(222, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(222, NULL, NULL, NULL);

UPDATE T1
SET T1.Label  = T2.Label,
    T1.Series = T2.Series,
    T1.Amount = T2.Amount
FROM T T1 INNER JOIN T T2 ON T1.ItemNo = T2.ItemNo AND T2.Label IS NOT NULL 
WHERE T1.Label IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM T;
```

Results:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | ItemNo | Label  | Series | Amount |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |    111 | Baer   | Toys   |      9 |
|  2 |    111 | Baer   | Toys   |      9 |
|  3 |    222 | Flower | Garden |      8 |
|  4 |    222 | Flower | Garden |      8 |
|  5 |    222 | Flower | Garden |      8 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```